# Unable to apply DjangoFilterBackend on API View

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two models `User` and `Role`. `User` model has a `foreign key` referring to `Role` model. I want to list users based on their `role_name`, the API should be able to `search` for fields like `first_name`, 'email' etc. and have a `pagination`.

**Search should be on filtered list only.**

URL would be like -

```
{{dev}}/user/list?role_name=Merchant&search=Shobraj&page=2
```

So, at first I installed  `django-filter` package then in setting.py added filter backend like this -

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
}
```

List API View -

```
class UsersListAPIView(ListAPIView):
 
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated & WhitelistAdmin]

    def get(self, request, formate=None):

        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ListUsersSerializers
        serialized_data = serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
        filterset_fields = ['role__role_name']
        print(queryset.query)

        return Response(serialized_data.data)
```

`print(queryset.query)` returns this -

```
SELECT `user_authentication_user`.`id`, `user_authentication_user`.`last_login`, `user_authentication_user`.`is_superuser`, `user_authentication_user`.`first_name`, `user_authentication_user`.`last_name`, `user_authentication_user`.`email`, `user_authentication_user`.`phone_number`, `user_authentication_user`.`password`, `user_authentication_user`.`company_name`, `user_authentication_user`.`is_active`, `user_authentication_user`.`role_id`, `user_authentication_user`.`businesses_id`, `user_authentication_user`.`service_cities_id` FROM `user_authentication_user`
```

I don't know why but filters are not applied on `queryset`.

The  existing List API View returns the list without filtering.

How can I make this API work with `filters`, `pagination` and `search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure but you set the filter after you serialized the data. In my opinion this does not work. you could try to set the filter_backends and the fields further up like this:

```
class UsersListAPIView(ListAPIView):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated & WhitelistAdmin]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['role__role_name']

    def get(self, request, formate=None):

    ...
```

Does this work for you?